# Meaning of Einstein's condition on the metric tensor

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, volume

Quote from *Nothing but coincidences: the point-coincidence and Einstein’s struggle with the meaning of coordinates in physics* by Marco Giovanelli:

> On November 11, 1915, Einstein returned to a set of generally covariant vacuum field equations that he had introduced in 1913:$$R_{\mu\nu} = \kappa T_{\mu\nu},$$where $R_{\mu\nu}$ is what we now call the Ricci tensor. He replaced the restriction imposed by the conservation laws with the requirement that the determinant of the metric satisfied the condition $\sqrt{-g}=1$.

What is the physical meaning of this condition that Einstein imposed on the metric tensor?

Comment: I am pretty sure that by Nov. 11th, 1915 Einstein knew that the spacetime 4-volume element is a pseudoscalar and not a scalar wrt to GCTs, so he took this restriction just as a simplification. Let us note that deriving the field equations from a Lagrangian density was Hilbert's idea. Hilbert had thus no reason to dismiss this factor by arbitrarily setting it to $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never really understood the line of thought behind Einstein's struggles with Riemannian geometry and general covariance, so this answer is given without the underlying context of the question.

Let $M$ be an $m$ dimensional manifold with local coordinates $x^\mu$ and line element $\mathrm ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm dx^\mu\mathrm dx^\nu$. Let $$ \rho=\sqrt{\left|\det (g_{\mu\nu})\right|}. $$

It is known from Riemannian geometry that if an infinitesimal parallepiped with vertices $(x^1,\dots,x^m)$, $(x^1+\mathrm dx^1,\dots,x^m)$, ..., $(x^1,\dots,x^m+\mathrm dx^m)$ is given, then the volume of this parallelepiped is $$ \mathrm dV(x)=\rho(x)\mathrm dx^1\dots\mathrm dx^m. $$

The coordinate condition $\rho=1$ then means that $$ \mathrm dV(x)=\mathrm dx^1\dots\mathrm dx^m, $$i.e. the coordinate volume coincides with the invariant/geometric volume.

This simplifies some formulae, for example if $f=f(x)$ is a function, then its integral over a coordinate region $D$ is calculated as $$ I=\int_Df(x)\mathrm dx^1\dots\mathrm dx^m $$with no additional factor here, and if $X^\mu$ is a vector field, its divergence is calculated as $$\mathrm{div}(X)=\frac{1}{\rho}\partial_\mu(\rho X^\mu)=\partial_\mu X^\mu, $$i.e. the divergence reduces to the Euclidean formula.

Geometrically, the condition $\rho=1$ means that the grid of coordinate lines is such that the parallelepipeds formed by the intersection of the coordinate lines have unit volume.

---

As $\rho=1$ is a *coordinate condition*, physical meaning (when $M$ is the four dimensional Lorentzian spacetime) can be ascribed to it only if it represents a nontrivial restriction on the nature of spacetime.

Consider for example another coordinate condition $$ g_{\mu\nu}=c_{\mu\nu}, $$where the $c_{\mu\nu}$ are constants. If this is the case, then the metric can be transformed into pseudo-Euclidean form by a linear transformation of the coordinates. Indeed, a general pseudo-Riemannian space *does not admit such coordinates*, and the integrability conditions for the existence of such coordinate systems is that the Riemann curvature tensor should vanish.

Hence, the physical meaning of $g_{\mu\nu}=c_{\mu\nu}$ is that the spacetime is flat.

However the condition $\rho=1$ is devoid of such a meaning, since *every* pseudo-Riemannian space admits an atlas of coordinate charts which satisfy this condition.

This can be seen by noting that if the function $$\phi(x)=\phi(x^1,\dots,x^m)$$ is given in a neighborhood of $x_0$ and does not vanish anywhere, then it is possible to make a coordinate transformation $$ \bar x^\mu=\bar x^\mu(x^1,\dots,x^m) $$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$ such that the Jacobian of the transformation is $\phi$. For example by taking $$ \psi(x^1,\dots,x^m)=\int_{x_0^1}^{x^1}\phi(s,x^2,\dots,x^m)\mathrm ds, $$ then $$ \phi=\partial_1\psi, $$ and if we define $$ \bar x^1=\psi(x^1,\dots,x^m),\quad \bar x^2=x^2,\dots,\bar x^m=x^m, $$ we have $$ \left(\frac{\partial\bar x^\mu}{\partial x^\nu}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}\phi & \partial_2 \psi & \cdots & \partial_m\psi \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\end{matrix}\right), $$ and the determinant of this matrix is $$\det\left(\frac{\partial\bar x^\mu}{\partial x^\nu}\right)=\phi. $$

Hence  if we take $\phi:=\rho$, we get $$ \bar\rho=\det\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \bar x^\nu}\rho =\frac{\rho}{\phi}=1. $$

Since every pseudo-Riemann manifold can satisfy the coordinate condition $\rho=1$, it does not restrict the spacetime manifold in any way and therefore has no intrinsic physical meaning.

Comment: *I never really understood the line of thought behind Einstein's struggles with Riemannian geometry and general covariance* I think, back in the day, it was not that well developed theory still expressing everything in coordinates?  On top of that, wasn't Einstein the first one actually looking at pseudo-Reimann manifolds? Today differential geometry seems natural and easy, but I guess that is due to the fact how much polish it got thanks to GR and the struggle to also account for pseudo-Riemannian manifolds and the shift to abstract language devoid of coordinate pollution.

Comment: @Umaxo Yes, at the time differential geometry was formulated fully in coordinates and Einstein had difficulty truly grasping the concept that coordinates do not have to have immediate metrical meaning. I also know that he thought the "hole argument" (essentially, gauge symmetry) makes the theory pathological and hence why he abandoned general covariance at first. What I don't know is why he thought the unimodular condition $\rho=1$ helps with all that, this is what I meant.

Comment: @BenceRacskó what does it mean that the theory is pathological? (Also thanks for your great answer, it helped me a lot)

Comment: @gianpaolo A theory with gauge invariance has ill-defined initial value problem. In GR you can specify some initial data, then make a compactly supported coordinate transformation which reduces to the identity at the initial data surface. Then both the original and the transformed metrics are solutions to the field equations associated to the *same* initial data. We now understand that this is okay and have the constrained Hamiltonian formulation to deal with it. In Einstein's time, this was thought to be anathema.