# Determinant of metric tensor in Cartesian Coordinates constant in vacuum

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

In 3D, the determinant of a metric tensor is related to the volume of the span of the basis vectors. In Cartesian Coordinates, it's just the volume of the cube.

I *would guess* that in ***4D space-time***, the determinant of the metric tensor ***in vacuum*** is related to the speed of light and, therefore, is ***constant***. (Edit:in cartesian coordinates)

In the Schwarzschild equation, at least, this is true. (Edit: The determinant of the Schwarzschild solution is that of spherical coordinates, therefore, in cartesian coordinates, it would be constant.)

However, is that true for every arbitrary metric tensor in vacuum?

Is that probably related to the fact that in vacuum, there are "no sources", therefore $T_{\mu\nu} $ = 0, therefore $R_{\mu\nu} $ = 0?

Can one derive $|g_{\mu\nu}|$ = constant from $R_{\mu\nu} $ = 0?

EDIT: Of course, the determinant of the Schwarzschild metric in spherical coordinates is not constant, but that of spherical coordinates. That brought me to the guess that probably, in Cartesian Coordinates it would be constant. My question therefore better reads as

1. "is the determinant of the metric tensor ***only*** dependent on the choice of coordinates and not dependent on the underlying (physical) space-time?" Or
2. "Is the determinant of the metric tensor of an arbitrarily curved spacetime in vacuum in ***Cartesian coordinates*** always constant?"

Comment: -1 Changing a question after it has been answered is impolite.

Comment: Sorry for that! However, I wrote _in the title_ that it's meant to be constant **_in cartesian coordinates_** and I realized that I didn't make it clear that I want to disentangle coordinates and curvature of space-time. I _know_ that it's dependent on the choice of coordinates. It's really tricky to disentagle physics-related curvature and a arbitrary choice of coordinates and I tried to make it clearer.

Comment: Cartesian spatial coordinates imply vanishing spatial curvature. You can’t *have* Cartesian coordinates in an arbitrarily curved spacetime.

Comment: Really??? But I could simply transform, for example, Schwarzschild metric, to cartesian coordinates. Then I would have cartesian coordinates - but curved space-time.

Comment: You seem to have a different definition of Cartesian coordinates than I do. What is it?

Comment: To me, cartesian coordinates are just x, y, z, t

Comment: That’s not a meaningful definition. Those are just names.

Comment: x, y, z, t and the jacobian is 1. Then the metric tensor _is_ only dependent on the curvature... Isn't it?

Comment: @MartyMcFly A Jacobian matrix is defined for a particular coordinate *transformation*, not an individual coordinate system. In this context, Cartesian coordinates on a patch of spacetime are a set of coordinates such that the metric tensor takes the form $\mathrm{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$ in the induced coordinate basis. Obviously such a metric has vanishing Riemann curvature, which is a coordinate-independent statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathrm{det}(g)$ is not coordinate-independent - it is a scalar density of weight $+2$ (or $-2$, depending on your convention) which generically changes across spacetime. In Minkowski space equipped with spherical polar coordinates, for example, $\mathrm{det}(g) = -r^4 \sin^2(\theta)$.

> Is the determinant of the metric tensor *only* dependent on the choice of coordinates and not dependent on the underlying (physical) space-time?

I'm not quite sure how to answer this. At any particular point, $\mathrm{det}(g)$ can be made to take any (negative) value by appropriate change of coordinates. The precise way that $\mathrm{det}(g)$ varies from point to point depends on what coordinates you choose. The curvature and topology of the underlying manifold determine what coordinate systems are possible, so in that sense affect how $\mathrm{det}(g)$ can change, but that's rather indirect.

> Is the determinant of the metric tensor of an arbitrarily curved spacetime in vacuum in Cartesian coordinates always constant?

Cartesian coordinates can exist only on manifolds (or at least, in neighborhoods) with vanishing Riemann curvature. In other words, if a Cartesian coordinate system exists in some patch of your spacetime, then that patch is flat.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added some edits to the question to clarify it. Regarding your answer, could you please explain what is "weight" of scalar density? And, please, how is a scalar density defined? I found here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/721000/meaning-of-einsteins-condition-on-the-metric-tensor that Einstein _started_ at the assumption that $\sqrt{-g} $ = 1. This is related to my question... Why did he do this? You say "it generally changes across space time". Could you please explain?

Comment: @MartyMcFly Sorry, weight $+2$, not $+1$. A scalar quantity remains invariant under changes of coordinate; a scalar *density* is scaled by $J^w$ under changes of coordinate, where $J$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix corresponding to the coordinate change and $w$ is the density's weight. In Cartesian coordinates, $\mathrm{det}(g)=-1$. If we switch to polar coordinates, the Jacobian determinant is $\mathrm r^2 \sin(\theta)$, and the metric determinant becomes $-\mathrm r^4 \sin^2(\theta)$, which is consistent with it being a scalar density of weight $+2$.

Comment: @MartyMcFly I've also edited my answer to address your follow-up questions.

Comment: Could you please explain what does "weight" and "scalar density" exactly mean?

Comment: @MartyMcFly I don't know how to explain it more exactly than I did in my previous comment. Can you explain which part of that you find unclear?

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear to me, your first comment was sufficient indeed. Another question: cartesian coordinates only work if the spacetime is flat. However, if I say that I _approximate_ an arbitrarily curved spacetime with small pieces of a cartesian grid, "tangent spaces" - is that possible?

Comment: @MartyMcFly Given any point $p$, we can construct [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates) in a (possibly very small) neighborhood of $p$. In such a coordinate system, $g_{\mu\nu} = \delta_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{3}R_{\mu\nu\sigma\tau}x^\sigma x^\tau + O(x^3)$.